Why .md5mesh store vertices in an atypical way?
As I know, the typical file of the three-dimensional model, which is equipped with a skeletal, represents the vertex as follows. Let's call it the classic way.

Position (x,y,z);
An array[n] of bone indexes that affect this vertex;
An array[n] of weights indicating the degree of influence of the bone on this vertex.

However, after reading this article (see Reading a md5mesh file)
I realized that md5mesh prefers a different way of representing the vertex. So each vertex is:

Weight index (startWeight) and count (countWeight).

At the same time, each Weight consists of:

Bone Index (joint);
Weight (bias), which determines the degree of influence of the given bone;
Position ( pos.x pos.y pos.z ).

Thus, when working with md5mesh, we find the vertex position using multiplication

finalPos = (weight[0].pos * weight[0].bias) + ... + (weight[N].pos * weight[N].bias)

We come to the conclusion that in the classical method, the vertex has one position, nevertheless, in md5mesh, each weight has a position and we need to multiply it all.
Q: What are the reasons for choosing this representation of vertices in md5mesh rather than the classical way?
Obviously, this has already been discussed somewhere. Please provide links
Why is this important to me?
I'm researching a game that saves vertices in a similar way. But it seems that when exporting to collada, we lose information, because we store the result of multiplication (see finalPos above) and not the weights of each vertices.
Each list of this question contains only items related to this question
